# What is a singleton/borg pattern? Why don't they work for me/where is my concept wrong?

Tags: python, singleton, instance

Similar questions has been asked many times, but I have problems understanding it. I was thinking that the Singleton or Borg pattern can be used to create only one instance of an object, or to share its state. I have a (working) test example which does not work as I expect. Either the code is incorrect, or I misunderstand the concept of singleton/borg patterns.

I used a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) and a [borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) pattern to create the following code in the file `borg.py`:

```
class Singleton(object):
  _instance = None
  def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
        class_._instance = object.__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
    return class_._instance



class MySingleton(Singleton):

    def __init__(self):
        self._list = []

    def add(self,x):
        self._list.append(x)

    def get(self):
        return self._list

class MyBorg(object):
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        # and whatever else you want in your class -- that's all!
        self._list = []

    def add(self,x):
        self._list.append(x)

    def get(self):
        return self._list
```

then a file `module.py`

```
from borg import MyBorg
myborg = MyBorg()
myborg.add(42)
print "just added something"
```

and finally the main code:

```
from borg import MyBorg
import module
myborg = MyBorg()
myborg.add(4711)
print myborg.get()
```

One should replace `MyBorg` by `MySingleton` in the latter two classes to use the Singleton instead of the borg.

Now, when I run the main code I clearly can see that `modules.py` is called first, adding a value to the list. After that, the Singleton/Borg pattern is also instantiated in the main code, and (another) value is added. I expected to have two values in the list (42 and 4711), instead I only have the latter value in the list.

It might be the case that the instance in `module.py` went out of scope and so whatever were done in `module.py` has been deleted. But what I need is some was of having an object to contain the same content, no matter where I use it.

How can I achieve this? How can I make sure, that when I create an instance of the object MyBorg (or whatever), it contains the value '42' in the list, as added in `module.py`? What pattern/mechanism should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behavior you're seeing is that in both cases `__init__` gets called every time you do `instance = WhateverClass()`.

Note that you are passing **the same instance** around.  However, that instance is getting it's `_list` attribute cleared in `__init__`.

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
            return class_._instance

class Foo(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    pass

a = Foo()
a.data.append('Never see this')
b = Foo()
print a is b  #True
print a.data  # []
```

Comment: Hmm good point. But where to set it to an empty list? I need to find out when the first instance is created? Or hardcode it in the `__new__` method of the Singleton?

Comment: Would it be good practice to adjust e.g. the borg pattern and write `__shared_state = {'_list':[]}` instead? I.e. to initialize what I need in the shared-state dictionary?

Comment: I don't generally consider singleton's to be a great thing anyway... modules make decent singletons in some cases (Though you can't subclass that).  Another thing that you could do is add an `initialized` variable to your Singleton API.  You'd set `class_._intstance.initialized = False` in `__new__`.  Then `__init__` in the subclass is responsible for setting `self.initialized` to `True` and not executing if `self.initialized` is `True`.